# How can I declare a table variable with a decimal variable as the identity seed?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using this, but I can't figure out why this doesn't work. SSMS won't give me a useful message other than syntax incorrect:

```
DECLARE @columnSeed DECIMAL
SELECT  @columnSeed = MAX([seeded_column]) + 1 FROM [table] (nolock) WHERE [conditions]
DECLARE @Temp_Table TABLE ([seeded_column] varchar(35) IDENTITY(@columnSeed, 1), [more columns])
```

I want to take the maximum value from a column in one table and create a temporary table variable with an identity column seeded with that previous maximum value.

Edit: OK, after digging around for into about dynamic SQL I think I've got what should work, but it still isn't:

```
DECLARE @columnSeed DECIMAL
[@columnSeed set properly]
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
      N'DECLARE @Temp TABLE (seeded_column decimal IDENTITY(@seed, 1) NOT NULL [more columns])',
      N'@seed decimal',
      @seed = @columnSeed;
```

All the info I get now is that I've incorrect syntax near '@seed'

Comment: why would you want to do that? Perhaps there is abetter method to get the results you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable as a seed. It is invalid syntax. The table variable is already implicitly created before the batch is executed and the variable assigned anyway.

The only way of doing this would be to concatenate the desired query and execute it. All usages of the table variable would need to be in the child scope.

```
DECLARE @columnSeed DECIMAL(18,0) = 10

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'DECLARE @Temp TABLE (seeded_column decimal IDENTITY(' + CAST(@columnSeed AS NVARCHAR(19)) +', 1) NOT NULL)
        INSERT INTO @Temp DEFAULT VALUES;
        SELECT * FROM @Temp;'

EXECUTE sp_executesql 
      @sql,
      N'@seed decimal',
      @seed = @columnSeed;
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing whatever it is you are doing anyway though.

You could just declare the table variable in the outer scope with a seed of `0` and add the desired offset to your `SELECT` queries from it for example.

```
DECLARE @columnSeed DECIMAL(18,0) = 10

DECLARE @Temp TABLE (seeded_column decimal(18,0) IDENTITY(0, 1) NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO @Temp DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO @Temp DEFAULT VALUES;

SELECT @columnSeed + seeded_column AS psuedo_seeded_column 
FROM @Temp;
```

Though the whole need for this seems suspect. You shouldn't normally care what the `IDENTITY` values are. If this is to prepare data that later is inserted into the table you are calculating `@columnSeed` from maybe just inserting it and using the `OUTPUT` clause to get the `ID` values inserted might be more appropriate and less at risk of concurrency issues.

Comment: I'm pulling values from a table and updating a field in that table that's not set up as an identity column, but giving it a value as if it were an identity column, but there's also some grouping (i.e. these records have the same value in column B so we're going to set their column A to the same value that is one higher than the MAX of that column on the entire table.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't use parameters in DDL. In other words, you won't be able to use `@seed` in the `IDENTITY` clause. Convert the seed to a string and shove it into your DDL manually. Something like this should work. (I don't have a SQL Server instance handy, so my apologies if there are any additional errors. The point is: Don't use parameters in DDL statements.)

```
DECLARE @columnSeed DECIMAL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1024)

[@columnSeed set properly]

SET @sql = N'DECLARE @Temp TABLE (seeded_column decimal IDENTITY(' || CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @seed) || N', 1) NOT NULL [more  columns])';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```